# Not able to upgrade Kafka cluster from 1.0.0 to 2.0

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to upgrade my Kafka cluster from Kafka 1.0.0 to Kafka 2.0 I stopped all the instances in the cluster and updated the server.properties file with -

```
inter.broker.protocol.version=1.0
```

I am upgrading from 1.0.0 and have not overridden the message format, so inter.broker.protocol.version is the only parameter that I have to update.

I restarted Kafka but nothing happens when I do 
`grep "Kafka version" /usr/local/kafka/logs/*`
or go inside libs folder I see 1.0.0, not 2.0 which suggests Kafka is still running on 1.0.0 can somebody please guide me what I am doing wrong?

Note: I am following the up gradation procedure from here
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#upgrade

Comment: You need to upgrade the packages too. You can't just update a property file (which should say 2.0, not 1.0)

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks, Can you provide some information on how to do that? I have a running cluster (which I can stop if needed) running Kafka 1.0.0

Comment: Well, how did you get Kafka? You downloaded it from somewhere, so from the same place, you need to get the latest version. Otherwise, the logs will always say the version you're currently running